# How to make a perspective in SVG?

Tags: svg

I want to superimpose texture so that would be like in reality

I made way (path) and the top img tag made the clip-path texture how to rotate the texture under the desired perspective?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
}

svg path {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

image {
  persective: 1000px;
  transform: rotateZ(300px)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/bQdMN47/image.png" alt="">

<svg viewBox="0 0 800 450" id="svg">
  <defs><clipPath id="pattern"><path d="M95,329 238,374 238,183 207,183 140,120 95,228 M137,294 137,224 157,219 158,294z"/></clipPath></defs>
<image href="https://i.ibb.co/YkvS1LC/brick-004.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" x="-200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"clip-path="url(#pattern)"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG doesn't support 3D transforms, so what you want to do is not possible.

What you can do instead is do the 3D image transform in CSS/HTML and then create a new clip-path that is a de-projection of the original clip path in SVG. It takes quite a bit of matrix math to manually calculate the new clip-path coordinates, so it's not a quick answer. I just threw a scale transform onto the clip path so you can get the idea.

WebGL would really be a better toolbox for 3D textures - if you've considered that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#brick-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: rotateY(-38deg);
  transform-origin: 9% 0%;
  clip-path: url(#clip-me);
}
```

```html
 <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bQdMN47/image.png" alt="">

 <img id="brick-overlay" src="https://i.ibb.co/YkvS1LC/brick-004.jpg"/>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 800 450" id="svg">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-me" transform="scale(1.6 1)"><path  d="M95,329 238,374 238,183 207,183 140,120 95,228 M137,294 137,224 157,219 158,294z"/></clipPath>
        </defs>
</svg>
```